# Using regex to alter digits pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text, replace

**Background**

I have the following df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['But the here is \nBase ID: 666666    \nDate is Here 123456 ', 
                                   '999998 For \nBase ID: 123456    \nDate  there', 
                                   'So so \nBase ID: 939393    \nDate hey the 123455 ',],
                      'ID': [1,2,3],
                       'P_ID': ['A','B','C'],

                     })
```

**Output**

```
    ID  P_ID    Text
0   1   A   But the here is \nBase ID: 666666 \nDate is Here 123456
1   2   B   999998 For \nBase ID: 123456 \nDate there
2   3   C   So so \nBase ID: 939393 \nDate hey the 123455
```

**Tried**

I have tried the following to `**BLOCK**` the 6 digits in between `\nBase ID:` and  `\nDate`

```
df['New_Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace('ID:(.+?)','ID:**BLOCK**')
```

And I get the following

```
  ID P_ID Text New_Text
0               But the here is \nBase ID:**BLOCK**666666 \nDate is Here 123456
1               999998 For \nBase ID:**BLOCK**123456 \nDate there
2               So so \nBase ID:**BLOCK**939393 \nDate hey the 123455
```

But I don't quite get what I want

**Desired Output**

```
  ID P_ID Text New_Text
0               But the here is \nBase ID:**BLOCK** \nDate is Here 123456
1               999998 For \nBase ID:**BLOCK** \nDate there
2               So so \nBase ID:**BLOCK** \nDate hey the 123455
```

**Question**

How do I tweak `str.replace('ID:(.+?)','ID:**BLOCK**')` part of my code to get my desired output?

Comment: Try `ID:\s*(\S+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['New_Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace(r'ID: *\d+ *', 'ID:**BLOCK** ')
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/C4N7EX/1) for a detailed break-down of the used regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

try `df['New_Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace('ID:(.+?)\n','ID:**BLOCK**\n')`

regexp match the shortest possible string, in your case ' '

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below piece of code to get your desired output,

```
df['New_Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace('ID:\s+[0-9]+','ID:**BLOCK**')
```

Output:

```
0    But the here is \nCase ID:**BLOCK**    \nDate is Here 123456 
1    999998 For \nCase ID:**BLOCK**    \nDate  there              
2    So so \nCase ID:**BLOCK**    \nDate hey the 123455
```

Regex Breakdown:

`'\s+' - to indicate space(s)`

`'[0-9]+' - to specify a number`